# "By now" vs "now"

Tags: adverbs

> The case is closed **by now**.
>
> The case is closed **now**.

What exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well (save for highly unusual situations - see the comments for one) only the second one is grammatical.  "By now" tends to be used only in the sense of a hypothetical or conjectural statement, where whether or not the thing has happened is in question.  So

> He should have got back home by now.

And

> He might have finished writing his novel by now.

Would both be valid uses of the phrase.

Comment: This answer should've been upvoted by now. +1.

Comment: The case should be closed by now.

Comment: @j.r. What is the difference between should have and should, as in my example?

Comment: Say there is a case being tried in the Courthouse.  A man is running down the block, with papers in his hand, which he wants to file in that case.  His friend sees him, and says: "You are probably too late.  Surely the case is closed by now."

Comment: It is not necessary that it be used hypothetically. "He *will* have gotten home by now" is common and not hypothetical.

Comment: @metaEd That statement is hypothetical in the sense that the speaker has no actual knowledge that the event spoken of has occurred.  Their knowledge is constructive based upon other facts.

Comment: @Noah: Not much of a difference at all.

Comment: No, *hypothetical* does not mean Uncertainty. It means *supposition*: something you assert as if it were true for the purpose of argument. In my example, nothing is being asserted as a supposition. Instead,a fact is simply being asserted to be true.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, when my coworker says "this is fixed by now", all he means is that he thinks it is. Good to know!

Comment: This is reaching, but I could imagine a narrative of past events in the present tense: "It is the middle of November. The case is closed by now. Yet Detective Smith is still convinced that..."